# What would you do without IoC frameworks in CF (aka ColdSpring, Lightwire, etc..?)

Tags: coldfusion

I've been doing ColdFusion for 2 years, and I've always used ColdSpring for injecting dependency.  I want to try to see if I can survive without them.  What're the alternatives?

For *singleton*:

onApplicationStart() and inject services to Application scope?

For *transient*:

Factory pattern? XXXFactory.createXXX()? or... XXXService.createXXX()?

Please comment, and share your alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Henry,

I would write a 'DIManager' CFC to manage my own dependencies and persist the 'DIManager' in the Application scope using onApplicationStart() so it would be available for the life of the application.

Each service would be responsible for creating the transients it services as you recommended within your question.

I would opt for using ColdFusion 9s cache methods within my 'DIManager' to manage the persistence of the singletons as I expect even greater support for machine storage mechanisms as ColdFusion evolves, and, you could define profiles for each singleton so that some expire after a period of time while others live for the life of the application. This would provide greater control than using the Application scope. However, the profile could place an object in a clustered scope, server scope, etc..., depending on what your specific challenge is.

***I almost*** went this route for a project I am about to complete, but, decided to not reinvent the wheel and simply went with ColdBox since it has fantastic caching abilities. I should also add, the ColdBox team has almost completed their goal of breaking the framework into separate units. The final separate piece is WireBox which should be released soon--so, if you have limitations on using a framework, dont like MVC or AOP, you can write your application in your own way and still use WireBox or the other great IoC frameworks that already exist (like the one you have been using :).

Hope that helps.

I look forward to other answers as well.

Comment: +1 Great answer .. I'm just getting into the ioc/di world and I've had a time trying to get used to all the features and complexity ... 

Louis Majano is coming to the SoFla CFUG and I'm really pumped about picking his brain a bit ... ;-) Between spring MVC, coldspring and coldbox I've got several years worth of goals mapped out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly cases cases where a DI framework hides some code smells, say passing in a pile of parameters automagically. By doing things by hand, or at least knowing what doing so would entail you'll make your designs cleaner. 
It's probably a bit like learning C, even if you don't use it often it good stuff to know.

There's an intersting article about [do-it-yourself DI](http://misko.hevery.com/2010/05/26/do-it-yourself-dependency-injection/) here that focuses on Java but might be worth your while.

Answer (score 0):

These are all great suggestions.  My main goal lately when setting up the family of supporting services and whatnot has been to brace for caching and divorce the application code from the API's inner workings.  Specifically, this translates into always using factories to generate transients and always having singleton services that receive requests from the application.

I don't think I can live without AOP anymore though.  I've been able to solve so many surprise issues with layered interceptors that I should really build a small shrine at my desk to worship AOP from.

So, in summary, when building your own solution try to implement singleton services and transient factories.  AOP is a huge bonus, but I couldn't tell you how to implement that.  I'm a ColdSpring user, and thankful it does what it does!